# How can I insert rows based on cell contents looped through all rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am trying to write a macro that tidies up and interrogates raw data exported from some analytical instrumentation. I would like it to look through one column (sample names) down all rows and look for indicators of specific sample types e.g. duplicates. Finding these indicators I want to insert a row, and in the new inserted row do some simple calculations based on the two rows above.  For now I will just be happy getting the row insertion to work.

I can get it to find the key word and insert 1 row, but it finds the first one and stops. There are multiple instances of these keywords in my data, and i want to insert a row below each

```
'original code - finds first keyword, inserts row and stops

Sub dup_finder()
    Dim colHeader As Range

    Set colHeader = Range("B1:B500")


Dim currCell As Range
Set currCell = Cells.Find("*_dup")

If Not currCell Is Nothing Then currCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown


End Sub

'my attempt to include loop - inserts 500 rows below keyword! stops 
after first instance

Sub dup_finder()
Dim colHeader As Range
Dim row As Long
Dim currCell As Range

Set colHeader = Range("B1:B500")

Set currCell = Cells.Find("_dup")
        For row = 1 To 500
If Not currCell Is Nothing Then currCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

 Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find every instance of "_dup" in column B and insert a row under each one?

Comment: When looping and adding (or deleting) rows, it's often better to start from the bottom and work your way up, the reason being when you add a row what was row 2 is now row 3 and what was row 500 is now row 501 (outside of your loop range).  So try going from 500 to 1 step -1 and see if that gets you better results.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `FindNext`. There are many examples of it on the web

Comment: Thanks for the help - not sure how to reply to specific replies.. but i will look up "FIndNext", and "Do you mean that you want to find every instance of "_dup" in column B and insert a row under each one? – SJR 7 mins ago" - yes, exactly this!  I then want to include a simple calculation in that new row, but first things first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest always fully qualifying your ranges with the workbook and sheet.

You should be able to adapt this to what you want. You simply enter the range you want to check in, and the value you are checking for.

It works backwards, up through the range, inserting a row below each one it finds.

```
    Sub InsertRows()
        ''Declare your variables
        Dim RngToCheck As Range, ValToFind As String
        ''Set the range in which to look for your desired string.
        Set RngToCheck = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B500")
        ''Set what string to look for.
        ValToFind = "_dup"

        ''Declare a variable to use as a counter
        Dim i As Long
        ''Count backwards through each of the rows in the range.
        ''(If you went forwards through the range, the rows you
        ''are inserting would become part of that range and push
        ''the bottom rows (which you intended to check) out of the range).
        For i = RngToCheck.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            ''Check if the last characters (the number of characters to
            ''check is defined by the length of the string we are looking
            ''for) of the current cell match the string we are looking for.
            If Right(RngToCheck(i).Value, Len(ValToFind)) = ValToFind Then
                ''Insert the row (we need to offset by 1 row
                ''because rows are inserted ABOVE, and we
                ''want it BELOW the current cell).
                RngToCheck(i).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
                ''Now you can add your formulas to the new row...
                ''column A
                RngToCheck(i).Offset(1, -1).Formula = "=1+1"
                ''column B
                RngToCheck(i).Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=2+2"
                ''column C
                RngToCheck(i).Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=A" & RngToCheck(i).Offset(1, 1).Row & "+B" & RngToCheck(i).Offset(1, 1).Row
                ''column D
                RngToCheck(i).Offset(1, 2).Formula = "Hello"
                ''And so on...
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: This works as well! Not being good at code i cant comment if yours is better than SJR's solution, but they give me an idea on different ways to do things - so i really appreciate that

Comment: No problem. I have added comments to the code for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the comments .. struggling to get my head around how/why there are so many different ways to do things - though i guess thats what grants such flexibility..  Would it be simplest to try and incorporate the formulas in the new row now, or run through another loop looking for the row below the  chosen string ("_dup")?  I will try a few things and probably come back with more questions.

Comment: You could do either but I would add the formulas now while you have a reference to the new row. I will update my answer.

Comment: i know the comments aren't meant for thanks yous... but thank you! really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do want to insert a row under every instance of a cell in column B containing "_dup" this should work.

The problem with your code was that it wasn't looping and so only ever found one instance.

It's advisable not to specify a fixed range as you are inserting rows and the range will expand; however, you could do this and set the search direction as "previous".

```
Sub dup_finder()

Dim colHeader As Range, s As String

Set colHeader = Range("B1:B500") ' not actually used

Dim currCell As Range

'are we searching just B or the whole sheet?
Set currCell = Columns(2).Find(What:="_dup", Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'change parameters to suit

If Not currCell Is Nothing Then
    s = currCell.Address             'store address of first found cell
    Do
        currCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Set currCell = Columns(2).FindNext(currCell)  'find next case
    Loop Until currCell.Address = s  'keep looping until we are back to the original case
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and really appreciate the comments included so i can follow along with what is happening.